# Can I solve for lambda in this equation?

Tags: probability-distributions, systems-of-equations

I am working with the exponential probability distribution and was hoping to find a parameter lambda that simultaneously satisfies this set of equations

\begin{align}
1-\exp\left(-2\lambda\right)&\leq .9\\
\exp\left(-7\lambda\right)&\geq .01
\end{align}

i.e., I want to find a $\lambda$ such that $Pr(X\leq 2)\leq 0.9$ and $Pr(X\geq 7)\geq 0.01$. Can I solve that system of equations for $\lambda$? I don't think so, but am looking for confirmation.

Also, if instead I had a 2 parameter distribution, would it then be possible? For example, if I instead had the following

\begin{align}
1-\left(1+\frac{2\lambda}{\sigma}\right)&\leq .9\\
\left(1+\frac{7\lambda}{\sigma}\right)&\geq .01
\end{align}

So instead now I would be solving for values $\lambda$ and $\sigma$ that satisfy that set of equatons.

Comment: The first inequality is equivalent to $0.1\le e^{-2\lambda}$. Can you solve ?

Comment: The second set isn't any more general than the first since it's the same set in the new variable $\lambda/\sigma$. I suggest you start by drawing the graphs if the first two. Desmos might do that for you.

Comment: @KurtG. $\lambda \leq -\log(0.1)/2$?

Comment: Correct. And the second inequality gives $\lambda\le-\log(0.01)/7\approx 0.65788$. Those $\lambda$ will also satisfy the 1st inequality.

Comment: @KurtG. I added a more updated version of the question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4439328/solving-for-the-parameter-of-an-exponential-distribution if you have time to take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are not equations, they are inequalities.  Any $\lambda \le \ln(100)/7 \approx 0.6578814551$ will do.

Comment: Can you show how you came to that solution?

Comment: Solve the two inequalities separately.

Comment: I added a more updated version of the question here: math.stackexchange.com/questions/4439328/… if you have time to take a look I'd greatly appreciate it.