# Solving for the parameter of an exponential distribution.

Tags: probability-distributions, systems-of-equations, exponential-distribution, simulation

Suppose I have a random variable $X$ where $X$ follows an exponential distribution of the following form:

$$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\lambda}e^{-\frac{x}{\lambda}}$$.

I want to find the value of $\lambda$ such that $Pr(X<10^{-8}) \geq 0.95$ and $Pr(X>6\times10^{-6}) \geq 0.001$.

So I have the following two inequalities to solve:

\begin{align}
1-\exp\left(-\frac{10^{-8}}{\lambda}\right)&\geq 0.95\\
\exp\left(-\frac{6\times10^{-6}}{\lambda}\right)&\geq 0.001
\end{align}

Solving the inequalities I have the following:
\begin{align}
\lambda & \geq \frac{-10^{-8}}{\ln(0.05)}\approx 3.338082e-09\\
\lambda & \leq \frac{-6\times 10^{-6}}{\ln(0.001)}\approx 8.68589e-07
\end{align}

So I would need to choose a value of $\lambda$ such that $3.338082e-09\leq\lambda\leq8.68589e-07$, correct?

However, when I try to verify this solution via simulation, I don't seem to get the right conclusion, i.e., assume I let $\lambda =  8.68589e-08$ then I have the following solution using `R`

```
> 
> lambda >= (-10^-8) / log(.05)
[1] TRUE
> lambda <= -(6*10^-6) / log(0.001)
[1] TRUE
```

So I am between those two values (so far so good). Now, I'll simulate a large number of random samples from the exponential with the value of $\lambda=8.68589e-08$ to check that I get the right probabilities:

```
> x <- rexp(10000000, 1/lambda)
> 
> sum(x < 10^-8)/length(x)
[1] 0.1085921
> sum(x > 6*10^(-6))/length(x)
[1] 0
```

And so from my simulation, I have that $Pr(X<10^{-8}) = 0.1085921$ and $Pr(X>6\times10^{-6}) = 0$

which is not what I want. Is my math/logic incorrect somewhere?

Also, here is a histogram of the random samples overlaid with the true exponential density in red. The two blue dashed line correspond to $6\times10^{-6}$ and $10^{-8}$

[Histogram of samples and true density](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ps1z.jpg)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135970/discussion-on-question-by-john-smith-solving-for-the-parameter-of-an-exponential).